Updating an old version of the OpenSSL library for Windows
On a Windows 32-bit program written in Delphi 7 and not updated since 2015 by its author, an error is returned after enabling an option to establish an SSL encrypted connection.
In the root folder of the program there are the files libeay32.dll, libssl32.dll and ssleay32.dll dating back to 2007 and 2008, belonging to the “OpenSSL Shared Library” version 0.9.8.5, product name “The OpenSSL Toolkit” version 0.9.8e.
I would like to update these files to try to solve the problem: where can I download the most suitable precompiled OpenSSL binaries for Windows ?

0.9.8 is frighteningly out of date! Do you have the original source for your Delphi 7 app? You cannot simply replace a 0.9.8 version of OpenSSL with the latest version. They are not binary or source compatible. At the very least you would most likely have to recompile/link against the latest version. Quite likely you will need to make source level changes to the Delphi application to adjust it to the latest OpenSSL APIs. You might be able to upgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.2 - this is still very out of date and vulnerable to many CVEs, but more recent than 0.9.8 and should be mostly compatible.

I do not have the source code of the original Delphi 7 application. The author released the latest version of the program in 2015 and does not respond to support requests.

@MattCaswell Here there is a link where you can download OpenSSL 1.0.2u dating back to 2019 but the corresponding libssl32.dll file is missing. Where can I find this file compatible with the other two ?

Try the Shining Light version: https://web.archive.org/web/20200122042845/https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Note by the way that 1.0.2 may not solve your problem depending on what the cause of the error is. 1.0.2 is also frighteningly out of date...

@MattCaswell Thank you, the 2019 version of OpenSSL 1.0.2u contains all the necessary files, but then I realized that the problem is not caused by the DLLs, in fact the same error appears even when deleting them. With Wireshark I found out that the encrypted connection is reset by the server, most likely because the program tries to establish a connection using an obsolete and not accepted Cipher suite.

You can download updated OpenSSL libraries from SLProWeb. Choose the 32-bit version to match your Delphi program, and replace libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in your app’s directory after backing up the originals. This ensures compatibility with modern SSL/TLS standards.

Thanks, I had tried it but the files inside are too recent and the problem seems to be caused by something else (See my last comment above)
